# How do I prove that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $ab | c$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

> How do I prove that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $ab | c$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$?

I got stuck with the following steps:

1. Express $c = ma = nb$ for some $m, n$ integers.
2. Multiply together the $2$ expressions to get $c^2 = mn(ab)$

But I cannot show that $c  = \frac{mn}{c}(ab)$ because $mn/c$ might not be an integer.

How do I use the result that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$?

Comment: Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$.  Multiply both sides by $mn$ to get $mnax+mnby=mn$ and simplify to get $cnx+cmy=mn=c(nx+my)$ and so $mn$ is in fact a multiple of $c$.

Comment: @JMoravitz isn't the goal is to show ab is a multiple of c instead of mn?

Comment: I was showing how you could salvage your approach since this shows $\frac{mn}{c}$ is infact an integer, allowing you to use your desired next step and reach a final conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: As usual, start with the fact that there are integers $k,\ell$ so that $ka+\ell b=1$. Multiply by $c$ to get $kac+\ell bc=c$. Can you see that $ab$ divides each term on the left?

Comment: Why would ab divide the terms on the left? Isn't ab not a multiple of either terms on the left?

Comment: You're confusing who's dividing whom :) Note, for example, that if $b|c$, then $ab|ac$.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of these results that is easier to think in terms of factors.

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, a, b and c factor uniquely. Since their GCD is 1, a nd b do not share any factors.

Can you see how the joke ends?

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid using fundamental theorem of arithmetic and use the fact that gcd(a,b) = 1?

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove $ab|c$ is to observe that $ma = n b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ imply that $b|m$. That is, $m = k b$. Therefore, $c = ma = k ab$.